# Sending SMS to contacts using MobileConnect inside Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, mobileconnect

With the Marketing Cloud Connector in place is it possible to send a SMS message to an individual Salesforce lead/contact from within Salesforce through MobileConnect?

Comment: Hi Kevin - did i manage to answer your question in full? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I asked Salesforce Support, they said that it is possible to do it with an APEX trigger, but that it's a regular API call towards marketing cloud. 
This seems to be the answer for your question.

However, there are mobile sends that can be initiated in my installation of the connector, albeit they seem to be not for any one individual, but for group messages. You could in theory create a segment of one, however, not sure you'd want to do that.

Depending on the volume on SMS messages you need to send, leverage a combination of lightning actions, APEX triggers and Batch APEX jobs.

**/* UPDATE */**

In my Marketing Cloud connect instead, there's a custom link you can add to a page which should allow you to send an sms. MobileConnect isn't enabled, so i can't test it. However, the functionality seems to be present.

The answer then becomes: How/When do you want to send the sms? If it's triggered - then the combo i mentioned is the way to go, alternatively, a field update combined with a journey entry can also do it. Depends, again, on use case.

**/* Update number 2 */**
You can use SMS interactions combined with Journey Builder and Salesforce Data Entry, to inject people into the journey, through which an SMS can be sent. Though, be aware that you need to opt people into a keyword first, to facilitate the send of SMS in the journey.

Let me know if there are questions to this one.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth! Yes, an APEX trigger was the route we took and are able to send SMS to a Contact from the Contact page.
On your UPDATE 1  I discovered the same custom links for Marketing Cloud, but it turns out that's leftover code from a Beta program that was not continued. You can connect to MobileConnect with it, but not send any messages.
Thanks for your thoughts on UPDATE 2, but we're trying to have more of a conversation enabled. Thanks again!